# How to execute SSIS packages on another SQL server's hardware?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2019

I have 20 ssis packages deployed on SQLSvr1 in the SSIS catalog.

They are invoked via the SQL agent jobs on this server.

Suppose I re-create these agent jobs on another SQL Server (SQLSvr2), then will they on the hardware resources of SQLSvr2 (CPU, memory)?

Answer (score 0):

The packages are going to execute and consume resources on whichever server they live on, which in this case would be `SQLSvr1`.

Also, SQL Agent Jobs just execute the steps inside them local to the server they're on (unless the step references a Linked Server, etc). So the Agent Jobs probably would fail on `SQLSvr2` if you tried running them without deploying your SSIS packages to `SQLSvr2`. The SSIS component of SQL Server would need to be installed and enabled on `SQLSvr2` as well.

Comment: Even assuming SSIS component is installed on Svr2, and the agent job on Svr2 calls packages located on Svr1, then am I correct that the packages will run only Svr1?

Comment: @variable Correct.

Comment: I'm so surprised as to why the SSIS buffer memory perf mon counter is recording 0! What do you recommend I do to check this?

Comment: @variable Wrong post, you asked about that in a different question. Unfortunately I don't much about PerfMon, haven't used it in years, and IMO it's not the best way to monitor stuff.

Comment: I cannot see dtexec process in my task manager, yet I can see multiple ssis packages are executed as evident on the servers ssis execution report. What am I missing?